# Optional React Router parameter

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to create a route that matches all of the following URLs:

```
/product/foo
/product/foo/bar
```

Here's my current route:

```
<Route path="/product/:productName(/:urlID)" handler={SomeHandler} />
```

According to the documentation on https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteMatching.md this route should match perfectly but **it does not match either of the URLs above**.

What do I need to do to support this optional parameter?

I'm on React Router version 0.13.3 and if I remove the `(/:urlID)` then I can match the first URL but not the second.

Comment: **For react-router versions** `1.0.0` **and above (including `2.x`), look** [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35604855/2030321)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so the () syntax is specific to React Router 1.0, not 0.13.3. I ended up using the ? syntax:

```
<Route path="/product/:productName/?:urlID?" handler={SomeHandler} />
```