# React Router with optional path parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to declare a path with an optional path parameter, hence when I add it the page to do something extra (e.g. fill some data):

> http://localhost/app/path/to/page <= render the page
>   http://localhost/app/path/to/page/pathParam <= render the page with
>   some data according to the pathParam

In my react router I have the following paths, in order to support the two options (this is a simplified example):

```
<Router history={history}>    
   <Route path="/path" component={IndexPage}>
      <Route path="to/page" component={MyPage}/>
      <Route path="to/page/:pathParam" component={MyPage}/>
   </Route>    
</Router>
```

My question is, can we declare it in **one** route? If I add only the second row then the route without the parameter is not found.

**EDIT#1:**

The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773911/optional-react-router-parameter) about the following syntax did not work for me, is it a proper one? Does it exist in the documentation?

```
<Route path="/product/:productName/?:urlID?" handler={SomeHandler} />
```

My react-router version is: 1.0.3

Comment: v6: React router seems to have dropped support for optional path parameters in v6, see https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7285#issuecomment-620071853 (and the discussion therein).

Comment: RRDv6-6.4.5 has alternatives/workarounds, and since v6.5 has had full support for [optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005601/alternate-way-for-optional-parameters-in-v6).

Answer (score 845, accepted):

The edit you posted was valid for an older version of React-router (v0.13) and doesn't work anymore.

---

## React Router v1, v2 and v3

Since version `1.0.0` you define optional parameters with:

```
<Route path="to/page(/:pathParam)" component={MyPage} />
```

and for multiple *optional* parameters:

```
<Route path="to/page(/:pathParam1)(/:pathParam2)" component={MyPage} />
```

You use parenthesis `(`  `)` to wrap the optional parts of route, *including* the leading slash (`/`). Check out the [**Route Matching Guide**](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax) page of the official documentation.

***Note:*** *The `:paramName` parameter matches a URL segment up to the next `/`, `?`, or `#`. For more about paths and params specifically, [read more here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/Glossary.md#params).*

---

## React Router v4 and above

React Router v4 is fundamentally different than v1-v3, and optional path parameters aren't explicitly defined in the [**official documentation**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/api) either.

Instead, you are instructed to define a `path` parameter that [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) understands. This allows for much greater flexibility in defining your paths, such as repeating patterns, wildcards, etc. So to define a parameter as optional you add a trailing question-mark (`?`).

As such, to define an optional parameter, you do:

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam?" component={MyPage} />
```

and for multiple *optional* parameters:

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?" component={MyPage} />
```

***Note:*** *React Router v4 is **incompatible** with [react-router-relay](/questions/tagged/react-router-relay) ([read more here](https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay/issues/193)). Use version v3 or earlier (v2 recommended) instead.*

Comment: This is still a question about multiple optional params in URL, like `/route(/:category/(:article)`

Comment: @AlexShwarc, good point, thanks. I added code to demonstrate multiple optional parameters. Have a look.

Comment: @Chris I'm sure, it doesn't work this way, have you checked that?

Comment: @Chris with 3 version

Comment: @Chris Try to check with one parameter supplied, what you get?

Comment: @AlexShwarc Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150718/discussion-between-chris-and-alex-shwarc).

Comment: @Chris @AlexShwarc what about this kind of path? Can you help me pls. `/tasks/45/notification/13` where `notification/13` is optional? Tried this `/tasks/:id(/notification/:notId)?` but it does not work!

Comment: @Chris ok, thanks! here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647427/react-router-4-with-optional-path-and-optional-parameter

Comment: Can I create optional path param to the main route ?
For example I need add language param to the path, and my homepage url will be "/" and "/en" [Here is demo](https://codepen.io/kholiavko-roman/pen/zpqKaa?editors=1010)

Comment: Please make sure That your index.html files includes the bundle.js as  `<script src="/bundle.js" /> not <script src="bundle.js" />`
If not, your route with optional param will not load the component

Comment: Do you know where I can read up on repeating patterns?

Comment: @Sam not sure what you mean exactly, but I'm thinking maybe using Regex might interest you?

Comment: Please note that the version of path-to-regexp supported from react-router is ^1.7.0, which is really old.

Comment: @chris Might want to update this answer for v6... Optional path parameters appear not to be supported. See https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7285#issuecomment-620071853

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki Thanks for the heads-up. As I am not using v6 myself, please feel free to update the answer to include v6

Answer (score 105):

For any React Router v4 users arriving here following a search, optional parameters in a `<Route>` are denoted with a `?` suffix.

Here's the relevant documentation:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string

> **path: string**
>
> Any valid URL path that [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) understands.

```js
    <Route path="/users/:id" component={User}/>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#optional

> **Optional**

#### Parameters can be suffixed with a question mark (?) to make the parameter optional. This will also make the prefix optional.

#### Simple example of a paginated section of a site that can be accessed with or without a page number.

```js
    <Route path="/section/:page?" component={Section} />
```

Comment: @user2928231 Thanks, updated with their new docs url. As far as I can tell `<Match pattern />` is now `<Route path />` again, but the question mark suffix remains the approach now for handling optional params.

Comment: Hi! I still have a problem with optional parameter and can't make next routes working: 

I have `players`, `players/123`, `players/123/edit`, `players?unseen=true`. 

The optional parameter `?unseen` doesn't work for me. though I tried all fixes from this discussion. Could you please help with the proper path string, which will handle this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @KhrystynaSkvarok, did you ever figure out how to get your path w/ an optional query string working? I'm trying to do the same

Comment: @sabliao Hi! I don't have a working example, but for URL like `example.com/search?query=test` try to use next pattern `/:search(search)`.

Comment: How can I get params from url after delimiter?

Comment: Please make sure That your index.html files includes the bundle.js as  `<script src="/bundle.js" /> not <script src="bundle.js" />`
If not, your route with optional param will not load the component

Answer (score 55):

Working syntax for multiple optional params:

```
<Route path="/section/(page)?/:page?/(sort)?/:sort?" component={Section} />
```

Now, url can be:

1. /section
2. /section/page/1
3. /section/page/1/sort/asc

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer for me as I was trying to figure out optional "directory paths" in the URL with react router v4.

Comment: Is there any way to support: "/section//1/" with page being ignored/optional.

Answer (score 50):

Well since you have mentioned your  react-router version as  1.0.3 you can find your solution among the previous answers.

However from **React Router v6** this option has been **removed** as mentioned. [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7285)

Hence for **React Router v6** the following :

```js
<Route path='/page/:friendlyName/:sort?' element={<Page/>} />
```

will be replaced by :

```js
<Route path='/page/:friendlyName/:sort' element={<Page/>} />
<Route path='/page/:friendlyName/' element={<Page/>} />
```

or you can also use :

```js
<Route path="/page/:friendlyName">
    <Route path=":sort" element={<Page />} />
    <Route path="" element={<Page />} />
 </Route>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30973721)

Answer (score 16):

for react-router **V5** use below syntax for *multiple paths*

```
<Route
          exact
          path={[path1, path2]}
          component={component}
        />
```

for **V6**

```
<Route path="/teams" element={<Teams />}>
  <Route index element={<TeamsIndex />} />
  <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
</Route>
```

Comment: I don't think this works with React Router v6..

Comment: For newer versions of React Router V6 you can also use the optional operator as stated here: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9546

Answer (score 7):

As with regular parameters, declaring an optional parameter is just a matter of the path property of a Route; any parameter that ends with a question mark will be treated as optional:

```
<Route path="to/page/:pathParam?" component={MyPage}/>
```

Answer (score 7):

As Sayak pointed out, optional parameters have been removed from React Router V6. The easiest solution I have found was to just make two routes. One for the url without the param and one with:

```html
<Route path="/product/:productName/" handler={SomeHandler} />
<Route path="/product/:productName/:urlID" handler={SomeHandler} />
```

Comment: Since optional parameters have been removed, how are you able to use "?" in your path?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That was actually a typo. The first path renders if there is no third param, the second path renders when there is a third param.

Comment: Looks like optional parameters are supported again: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9546

Answer (score 2):

Optional route segments are back in v6.5! https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9546