# How to set an optional parameter on root route in react-router v4?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

Let's say I have the following 2 routes:

```
    ...
    <Route exact path="/:param1?/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/news" component={News}/>
    ...
```

now when I try to hit route `/news` the root route for `Home` with the parameter `param1` is triggered...

I assume the solution would be to set a questionmark before the param1 like this `/?param1` so it can be held appart from the routes, but I can not figure out how to do this in react-router v4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router with optional path parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter)

Comment: absolutely not, I know how to set optional parameter, (which is the question in your link)! My question is more about how to differentiate between the parameter and another route... see the answer below...

Comment: Alright... just trying to help :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an example of how to do this in the official docs. You can find that [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/ambiguous-matches).

You'll need to use the Switch component with your /news Route being first.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/news" component={News}/>
    <Route exact path="/:param1?/" component={Home}/>
</Switch>
```

Switch will always only render one Route. So in the case above, if /news doesn't become active, then /:param1 will be.

Comment: Hey man, could you please help me how to create router for homepage with optional path (for example language)
I try something like this:


`<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/:language?" component={FirstPage} />
    <Route exact path="/:language?/add" component={AddPage} />
</Switch>`


but in this case the second route does not work correctly without language params.