# Navigating to optional parameters with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to make optional sub routes with my React Router but no matter what I search I can't seem to find a solution that works for me !

I tried every solution mentioned in this answer: 
[React Router with optional path parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter)
 - nothing worked.

So I have the following in one file:

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider> , document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

and then:

```
 export default (
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
     <Route path={'/'} component ={ApplicationHomePageContainer}></Route>
     <Route path={'/home'} component ={UserHomePageContainer}></Route>
     <Route path={'/circle(/:path)'} component ={CirclePageContainer}></Route>
    </Router>
 )
```

I have tried many many different approaches, but whatever I seem to do, the route `/circle/whatever` never renders anything.
All other work perfectly fine.

I am using React router version 2.8.3, I tried to upgrade to version 3 but that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its good but this is how I do it :

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path={'/circle'} component ={CirclePageContainer}></Route>
    <Route path={'/circle/:path'} component ={CirclePageContainer}></Route>
</Router>
```

Then I let the CirclePageContainer component handle the scenario when there is no parameter

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out what I was doing wrong.

So I had this on my backend:

```
server.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

And I only had to change my html folder from:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```