# How to set route with optional query parameter using React router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string

I have a path as

```
 <Route path="/account/:accountid/LoginPage"
      component={LoginPage}/>
```

This works fine if the url is -> `/account/12332/LoginPage`. I want to have optional query parameters. Url structure would be something as

```
/account/12322/LoginPage?User=A&User=B
```

I have modified the path as

```
<Route path="/account/:accountid/LoginPage(/:User)"
      component={LoginPage}/>
```

after this if I try to access the url it does not redirect me to the appropriate page instead it throws an error as

```
useBasename.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: history.getCurrentLocation is not a function
    at Object.getCurrentLocation (useBasename.js:56)
    at Object.getCurrentLocation (useQueries.js:64)
    at Object.listen (createTransitionManager.js:246)
    at Object.componentWillMount (Router.js:97)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:347
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:346)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router with optional path parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter)

Comment: I tried but it didnot solve my problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of react-router v4 (latest version), it does not support query params (? user=nerve&name=no-one). It does support URL params though. There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410) discussing the same point. Go ahead and read it, there are some good solutions but nothing baked right into the core library.

A workaround that I usually implement is adding multiple routes that render the same component.

```
<Route exact path='/' component={ HomePageConnector } />
<Route exact path='/search/:searchTerm' component={ HomePageConnector } />
```

### Edit

The only issue with v4, as I understand, is that it NO LONGER exposes the `location.query` object. However, you still have access to `location.search` (which is a STRING, not an object). You can read this string and pass it to a library like [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) to get a more meaningful object out of it. This way, you can continue to use query parameters rather than URL params. This information is already written in the GitHub issue but is a little scattered across comments. Something like (though not tested):

Routes:

```
<Route exact path='/test' component={HomePageConnector} />
```

Fetching the params in component:

```
const parseQueryString = require('query-string');

let queryString = this.props.location.search;
let queryParams = parseQueryString.parse(queryString);
```

Comment: This seems to be good for single route ...what if i had similar situation for multiple routes how can i solve the same

Comment: I am new to reactjs.....now i didn't know how to use your answer....kindly help me