# How to add attributes to react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add attributes on my `<Route>` from react-router-dom. When I just add it inside the path, the default route is fired instead. An example of what I would like to work, but do not, since the default route is used instead:

```
        <Route path="/myurl?myattribute=attributevalue"><MyComponent /></Route>
```

It seems like the Route path do get confused with the questionmark. If I just change it to something else, like an amperstamp, it "works". However, It is not that format I want. I want the regular `?`

I can not find documentation on how I can make something like this work. I have seen something about the `:id` part of the url, but I do not quite understand it.

Thank you for all help

Comment: Remove `exact` works for this

Comment: Woops, I forgot to remove it from the question. I have tried both, with and without, but neighter works @keikai

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216569/how-to-get-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4. You can use search parame inside your consumer component

Answer (score 0):

We don’t need to define query params in the route definition because by default it will be handled by the react router and send the query params into a props to the component

Check this out :

https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-handle-query-params-in-react-router/

More Info:

[How to set route with optional query parameter using React router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026915/how-to-set-route-with-optional-query-parameter-using-react-router)