# React Router 4 with optional path AND optional parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Need to declare an optional path that contains a string and a parameter
Now I have this path

```
<Route exact path="/tasks/:id" render={(props) => (
  <AsyncTask {...props} profile={this.state.profile} />
)} />
```

I need to have

```
/tasks/:id/notification/:notificationId
```

Where `notification/:notificationId` is optional
I tried to add it this way, but it does not work

```
/tasks/:id/(notification/:notificationId)?
```

I need this to know if I am coming from a notification link, to mark it as read.

This is working

```
/tasks/:id/(notification)?/:notificationId?
```

But it matches and paths without `notificationId`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. The ideal way would be to create two separate Routes for your purpose.

```
<Route exact path="/tasks/:id" component={...} />
<Route exact path="/tasks/:id/notification/:notificationId" component={...} />
```

---

If you **really must** only declare one Route, you could use a custom regex rule (the part that is wrapped in parentheses after the parameter name declaration):

```
<Route exact path="/tasks/:id/:notificationId(notification/\d+)?" component={...} />
```

**However!!** - note that the `notificationId` parameter will include the substring `"notification"`. For example, if you have:

`tasks/123/notification/456`

You will have a `taskId` of `"123"` and `notificationId` of `"notification/456"` (the whole string)!

That said, the route above will match the following paths:

- `tasks/123`
- `tasks/123/notification/456`

but not:

- `tasks/123/notification`
- `tasks/123/notification/abc`
- `tasks/123/456`

etc...

---

**TL;DR** - You probably want to use two individual routes as shown in the first example above.

Comment: I will go with 2 routes, or using query params as @Matt mentioned above. Thx for answer. Regex way is also a good idea.

Comment: @AndrewLuca, yes; it adds some flexibility.

Comment: In case someone is wondering, this does not remount the component, so it's really ok to define 2 routes for the same component.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there isn't any support for this in React Router [[1](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/929)].  Maybe you could just use a query parameter instead?  `/tasks/:id?notification=notificationID`.

Comment: It makes sense, because this type of URL is temporary. Thanks!