# Exclude a value for a path parameter in React Router by type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, coercion

I'm a bit stuck with the route component. Imagine I have this two Routes with their own path:

```
<Route path='/person/add' exact component={PersonForm}/>
<Route path='/person/:id' exact component={PersonView}/>
```

**/person/add** should show a form where I can create a new Person
**/person/:id** should show a person with the given id.

The problem >> If I navigate to **/person/add** it will also show the component of **/person/:id** because the string "add" is valid for ":id".

Is there a way I can avoid this? For example by telling that :id should be a number?

Comment: `/person/add` should just be `/person` then the state where there is no parameter is the add state and you can reuse it for editing. It makes sense :p

Comment: You may find this of interest https://stackoverflow.com/a/35604855/1915893

Comment: @AluanHaddad That's indeed how I solved it, but still I was questioning if there is another solution for it. Thanks!

Comment: I see. I'm sure there is a way but determining what strings are valid numbers in JavaScript is a source of much consternation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found a possible solution: You can use **Switch** around the routes. Then it will only match on the first one that matches.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/person/add' exact component={PersonForm}/>
  <Route path='/person/:id' exact component={PersonView}/>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having is that I had several routes;

```
/locations/:locationId
/locations/new
```

But when using the `matchPath` function from `react-router` it would return a false-positive for `/locations/:locationId` when I was on `/locations/new`. I solved this by passing a custom regex to my identifier;

**`/locations/:locationId([a-z0-9-]{36})`**

This will check if my "locationId" is a uuid and otherwise it won't match. It's probably also possible to exclude words like "new/edit/add"

[image]

These sources helped me;

- https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters
- https://regex101.com/