# How Can I Have Optional *Non*-Parameter URL Parts?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

[This Stack Overflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter) explains how to define React Router (v4) routes which contain multiple optional parameter, eg.:

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?" component={MyPage} />
```

However, it doesn't explain how to put optional text in-between those parameters, for instance:

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam1?/otherParam/:pathParam2?" component={MyPage} />
// Should match /to/page/1 AND /to/page/1/otherParam/2
```

This was certainly possible in previous versions of React Router, but I can't see how to do it in the current version.  Is there any way to specify optional parameter/non-parameter pairings, or even just optional non-parameters?  Something like:

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam1?/(otherParam/:pathParam2?)" component={MyPage} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React router uses `path-to-regexp` - https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

You can match optional non-parameters with a path like this:

```
const path = "/to/page/:pathParam1?/(otherParam)?/:pathParam2?"
```

And to test it:

```
const re = pathToRegexp(path)

console.log(re.exec("/to/page/1"))
// ["/to/page/1", "1", undefined, undefined]

console.log(re.exec("/to/page/1/otherParam/2"))
// ["/to/page/1/otherParam/2", "1", "otherParam", "2"]
```

Comment: Wow I was actually pretty close with my pseudo syntax; thanks!  And a pox on `react-router` and its constantly changing, poorly documented API ;)