# React-router optional path parameters at root

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I am a little confused on how to do (multiple) optional path parameters from the root. I'm using **react-router 3**, and redux 4.3.

From what I understand, `(/:param1)(/:param2)` should work, but I am getting the following error when loading the app:

> [react-router] Location "/property/3633" did not match any routes.

**index.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { Router, browserHistory, Route } from 'react-router';

import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

import {MyContainer} from "./containers/MyContainer";

const store = configureStore();
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/(/:Type)(/:Id)" component={MyContainer}/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

FYI I have tried:

```js
path="(/:Type)(/:Id)" 
path="(/:Type)/(/:Id)" 
path="/(/:Type)/(/:Id)" 
path="/(/:Type)(/:Id)" 
path="/:Type/:Id" // Only works when params are supplied
```

And this works:

```js
<Route path="/test(/:Type)(/:Id)" component={MyContainer}/>
```

But again, this does not:

```js
<Route path="/(/:Type)(/:Id)" component={MyContainer}/>
```

Comment: how about `path="(/:Type)(/:Id)"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue today. I managed to resolve it like this:

```
<Route path="/(:param1)(:/param2) component={SomeComponent}"
```

Comment: This works for me, not sure how I missed that configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some realtive path, rather than directly giving params. `<Route path="/get/(:Type)/(:Id)" component={MyContainer}/>`

Comment: he is using react-router v3

Comment: `<Route path="/:Type/:Id" component={MyContainer}/>` does work IF those params exist, if not then I get an error: `Location "/" did not match any routes`. And yes react-router **v3**

Comment: @ians You need to add some realtive path, rather than directly giving params. <Route path="/get/:Type/:Id" component={MyContainer}/>

Comment: @ChasingUnicorn `<Route path="/test(/:Type)(/:Id)"  component={MyContainer}/>` works. So there is no way to add optional params at the route?

Comment: Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter . This might help.

Comment: Upvoted thanks, still looking for an answer though:(