# Simple React Router with an Optional Path Parameter gives 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have this simple enough React app (created with `create-react-app` 1.5.2, and fluff removed). It has by default installed `react-router` 4.2.0.

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import history from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const App = ({
    params
}) => (
    <div>
        We are here: {params.filter}
    </div>
);

const Root = () => (
    <Router history={history()}>
        <Route path="/:filter?" component={App} />
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am using the syntax described in following answer to create an optional path parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40872420/1461424

However, this renders the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` at:

```
         <p>We are here: {params.filter}</p>
```

Using old style `/(:filter)` renders a blank page. So is `(/:filter)`.

I have read a number of similar questions, but none matched my issue. So my question is: How can I declare an optional path parameter inside my `Root` component, and then read the parameter from my `App` component?

Comment: the `App` component has no input param

Comment: @Kai: Sorry, did not get you. Shouldn't `({ params }) => ...` do that?

Comment: the answer below is what I mean xD!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in React Router v4 you should use a different prop, [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match):

```
const App = ({
    match
}) => (
```

which will then contain params:

```
    <p>We are here: {match.params.filter}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @César. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. :)