# Optional React Router Param Flagging GET request Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

EDIT: Posted answer to how I went around this instead of using react-router optional params.

For some reason, I'm having a GET error when I go to the optional react-router route/url with the optional param attached to the URL. I'm trying to track where a user came from by including the optional param SRC to the url. I've tried everything from /ref=testing, /src=testing, /testing as the :referrer? and they'll save probably in localStorage, but still raise the console GET request.

Here is what my App.js looks like:

```
<Route exact path="/profile/user/:user/:referrer?" component={ ProfileById } />
```

:user is the user ID in the mongoose structure. :referrer? is the src=(whatever it is)

Here is my axios request for the route:

```
export const getProfileByUserId = (user) => dispatch => {
dispatch(setProfileLoading());
axios.get(`/profile/user/${user}`)
    .then(res => 
        dispatch({
            type: GET_PROFILE,
            payload: res.data
        })    
    )
    .catch(err => 
        dispatch({
            type: GET_PROFILE,
            payload: null
        })   
    );
}
```

Here is what's inside my componentDidMount() where I run the axios GET request, and then also check for the optional param and store it in localStorage.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.match.params.user) {
        this.props.getProfileByUserId(this.props.match.params.user);
    }

    if (this.props.match.params.referrer) {
        let referrerString = this.props.match.params.referrer.split('=');
        localStorage.setItem('referrer', referrerString[1])
    }
}
```

When I load the route, let's say its: /profile/user/20385h1058h385/ref=testing  the GET error comes up as: 404 Not found, and then says the error is /ref=testing   Well if it's an optional param and I'm not actually requesting a GET on this optional param, why is it coming up?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it working with a react optional param route, so I just went ahead and did a new URLSearchParams(), made it into a string and then split that string to identify the actual search query. Works on a slash path like: /?src=testing and when it's appended to an existing path.

Here's what I came up with:

```
if (this.props.location.search) {
        // Check to see if the search address has a location and search query param, if so save in localStorage for referrer source
        //console.log(this.props.location.search);
        let srcParams = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
        let srcString = srcParams.toString();
        let referrerString = srcString.split('=');
        localStorage.setItem('referrer', referrerString[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please append, only `testing` instead of  `ref=testing` in the URL. In that case, your URL will be `/profile/user/20385h1058h385/testing`

We put `:` for the required parameter and `:parameter_name?` for the optional parameter.

For example :

```
<Route path="/login/:p1/:p2?" component={Login} />
```

Here p1 is the required parameter and p2 is an optional parameter.

And we get these in the componentDidMount method as you are doing.

```
this.props.match.params.p1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already tried removing the ref= or the src= in the url, and just did the /testing like you mentioned. I tried it again, and it's still getting the 404 GET error.

Comment: Which version of react-router you are using. Please look at this post as well `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter`. Up to version3, there is the same way to pass params, but after version4 the way is slightly different.

Comment: I am using React Router V5. Do you know what might be causing the GET error?

Comment: @Buckyx55, I have tested it today with V4. It is working fine for both optional and required parameter. You may have another issue.