# How can I display a specific header for a specific group of pages. Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

On my Gatsby website, I have a main header, for most pages, and a `SpecialHeader` for specific pages.

In my `Layout` file, which holds the header, page children, footer, etc, I have added this condition:

```js
        {location.pathname === ('/special-page/' || '/special-page') ? (
          <SpecialHeader currentPathname={location.pathname} />
        ) : (
          <MainHeader currentPathname={location.pathname} />
        )}
```

I would like to only show the `SpecialHeader` for pages that include the path `/special-page`. Is there a better way to do this?

There will be additional subpages (`/special-page/foo`) that will need the same header. Is it possible to show the special header if only the `/special-page` path is present? For example something like `/special-page*`

I hope I make sense. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `react-router-dom`
There is a feature for optional path parameters:

- Optional parameter

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam?" component={MyPage} />
```

- Multiple optional parameters

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?" component={MyPage} />
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by removing the forward slashes and getting the first word in the path. If there was a match in the name of the path, I would should the correct header.

For example:

```js
const stripPath = location.pathname.split('/')[1];
const isSpecialPath = stripPath === 'special-page' ? true : false;

{isSpecialPath ? (
  <SpecialHeader currentPathname={location.pathname} />
  ) : (
  <MainHeader currentPathname={location.pathname} />
)}
```