# From static pagination to dynamic

Tags: reactjs, pagination, fetch, router

Need help with pagination. Right now my app can change page, but if I want send request like `/character?page=4` it always throw me `/character?page=1` [this is not help](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-uhczc?file=/demo.js:455-521), coz I use router. I have no idea how to resolve my problem

My `app.js`

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/character' component={AllCharacters} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}
```

`CharacterList.jsx`

```js
    // API Data
    const url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character";
```

```js
    // Fetching Page
    const fetchPage = (page) => {
        // Init loading while page load
        setLoading(true);
        const query = `${url}?page=${page}`;
        fetchData(query);
        setLoading(false);
    };
```

```js
    // Change pages
    const { push } = useHistory();
    const handleChanger = (event, page) => {
        fetchPage(page);
        push({
            pathname: "/character",
            search: `?page=${page}`,
        });
    };
```

```js
                <Pagination
                    count={info.pages}
                    showLastButton
                    showFirstButton
                    onChange={handleChanger}
                />
```

Comment: What is the code for "Pagination" and did you checked if onChange is working and setting correct value for page?

Comment: Pagination is Material-ui component. Yes, I checked onChange, its works fine

Comment: See if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35604855/16441330

Comment: its not resolve

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Pagination : `App.js`

```
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/character/page=:page' component={DynamicPagination} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}
```

Dynamic pagination Demo : `DynamicPaginaton.js`

```
export default function DynamicPagination() {
      const history = useHistory();
      const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
      const [pageCount, setPagcount] = useState(10);
      const handlePageChange = (event, value) => {
        history.push(`/character/page=${value}`)
        setPage(value);
      };
    
      return (
        <div >
          <Typography>page:{page}</Typography>
          <Pagination
            count={pageCount}
            page={page}
            onChange={handlePageChange}
            style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: For my app there a no difference between ```history.push(`/character?page=${value}`);```
and without useHistory. Still dont work like I want