# URL parameter with React-Router

Tags: reactjs

//ArticlePage

```
const ArticlePage = ({ match }) => {
    const name = match.params.name;
    return (
    <>
        <h1>
            This is {name} Article
        </h1>
    </>
);
    }
export default ArticlePage;
```

//App

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";
import ArticlePage from "./pages/ArticlePage";

function App () {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes> 
          <Route exact path='/' element ={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path = '/topic' element = {<Topic />} />
          <Route path = '/about' element = {<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path = '/article/:name' element = {<ArticlePage />} /> 
          <Route path = '*' element = {<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

//NavBar Page

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavBar.css';

const NavBar = () => (
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li className='li'>
                <Link to ="/" className='link' > Home </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='li'>
                <Link to ="/about" className='link' > About </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='li'>
                <Link to = "/article" className='link'> Article </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='li'>
                <Link to = "/topic" className='link' > Topic </Link> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
);

export default NavBar;
```

[image]

**I am trying to pass URL parameter using variable 'name' but soon as i access ArticlePage I get 404:Not Found (content of my NotFound Page) .I'm trying to get value of 'name' variable using props (match) in ArticlePage but I'm unable to render it. Fairly new to React, any hint or solution would be appreciated. I'm using React v6. **

Comment: Link's to attribute should have `"/article/some_name"` I guess. Also, you should use `useParams` to get the URL parameters.

Comment: That's a fairly different thing here 'name' refer to variable. As far as i learnt variable is passed like that!

Comment: I meant Link in your Navbar not the Route. Like this `<Link to = "/article/some_name" className='link'> Article </Link>`

Comment: That doesn't even make sense article here link to one of my Article Page. I have issue with URL parameter. If someone type '/article' he should refer to my article main-page but if someone type '/article/learn-react' then i want to refer him to that page using URL parameter.

Comment: Then you should probably add a separate route for that.

Comment: I can do it that that would be quiet static .I wanted to make it dynamic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router with optional path parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240601/discussion-between-arya-singh-and-kiner-shah).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it's works

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ArticlePage = () => {
   const params = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        This is {params.name} Article
      </h1>
    </>
  );
}
export default ArticlePage;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to pass match as parameter while using useParams.

Comment: No need pass `match` in parameter ! i update my answer

Comment: Can you refer any article about usage of match and useParams beacuse I'm bit confused though it solves my problem.

Comment: For more help https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-use-react-router-useparams-436851fd5ef6