# React-Router: pass props from one component to another using link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I set up an app with 3 pages, Home, Reptiles and Map.

My problem comes on the Reptiles and Map page. On the reptiles page, I display a list of species, each with a list of range countries and a link "See Map Here". When the user clicks on a country, I want the Map page to be shown with the selected country highlighted (I haven't implemented that yet, so, for now, I just want that country to be passed to the map page).

And when the user clicks on a "See Map Here" for a species, I want the Map page to be shown with all the range countries of that species to be highlighted. Right now I can pass in reptile and country props in the Route for react-router, but when I try to pass in the props in the link directly in the Reptlie.js file, I get the error Warning: Unknown prop `reptile` on  tag.

Remove this prop from the element. Can someone help me figure out how to pass props to links directly in components? Also, how would you generate dynamic URLs? For example, map/species1 or map/country1?

I think my problem is in Reptiles.js. The version of react-router is 3.0.2

Below is my structure:

[image]

Below are some images:
[image]
[image]

Below is my code:
router.js:

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={App}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="reptiles" name="reptiles" component={Reptiles}/>
        <Route path="map" name="map" component={Map} country="Taiwan" reptile="Beardy"/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <span className="icn-logo"><i className="material-icons">code</i></span>
          <ul className="main-nav">
            <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/reptiles">Reptiles</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/map">Map</NavLink></li>
          </ul>       
        </header>
        {this.props.children}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Reptiles.js:

```
const Reptiles = () => {
  let reptiles = ReptileList.map((reptile) => {
    return (
      <li className="reptile" key={reptile.id} >
        <img className="reptile-img" src={reptile.img_src} />
        <h3>{reptile.name}</h3>
        <h4> Range &nbsp; &nbsp; 
            <span className="seeMap">
                <NavLink to="map" reptile={reptile.id}>  
                See Map Here 
                </NavLink>
            </span>
        </h4> 
            {reptile.range.map(function(country,index) {
                // only add comma if it's not the last one
                return <span key={country}><NavLink to="map" country={country}> {(index < reptile.range.length-1)? country+',' : country} </NavLink></span> 
            })
            }

      </li>
    );
  }); 

  return (
    <div className="main-content">
      <h2>Reptiles</h2>
      <ul className="group">
        {reptiles}    
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Reptiles;
```

Map.js

```
var Map = React.createClass({

  render: function() {


    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Country passed from props: {this.props.route.country} </h2>
            <h2>Reptile passed from props: {this.props.route.reptile} </h2>
        </div>
    )

    }

});



export default Map;
```

Comment: I added all my code to this repo along with the goals of the map page to the readme: https://github.com/jhjanicki/react-reptile-app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In route.js, you can pass the parameter as follows:

```
<Route path="map/:countryName/:reptileId" component={Map} name="map" />
```

In Reptile.jsx,Pass the parameters selected like from props.country or from state wherever you have stored. Make sure to pass some default values in the link when not applicable. For example, for the country in the first link, I have passed all. You can pass according to your requirements. You can pass the parameters as:

```
<NavLink to={`map/${reptile.id}`}>      

<NavLink to={`map/${country}/${reptile.id`}>
```

and access these parameters through context in Map.jsx `this.props.params.reptileId`

**More about parameters**

Like in your case, the parameter reptile id is must in both the cases and country is needed only in the case where specific country is clicked. Hence you can make the parameter country optional and reptile id compulsory. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773911/optional-react-router-parameter)

```
<Route path="map/:reptileId(/:countryName)" component={Map} name="map" />
```

and then pass accordingly.

```
<NavLink to={`map/${reptile.id}`}>      

<NavLink to={`map/${reptile.id}/${country}`}>
```

Comment: I tested it and just to start off simple i only tried it for reptile. In router.js I changed route to: <Route path="map/:reptileId" component={Map} name="map" /> and in Reptiles.js I changed the NavLink to <NavLink to="map/${reptile.id}"> See Map Here </NavLink> but I'm getting this error: Warning: [react-router] Location "/map" did not match any routes. But I don't have a link to "map" anywhere. Any idea why?

Comment: Does the reptile.id has any value?

Comment: this is what I get in the url: http://localhost:8080/map/$%7Breptile.id%7D but the map page wouldn't open. just in case you need more details I created a repo github.com/jhjanicki/react-reptile-app

Comment: Sure. Let me check!

Comment: ES6 recommends usage of back ticks instead of quotes

Comment: Access the params in url in Map.jsx through `this.props.params.reptileId`

Comment: thank you for your help, I haven't been able to get it to work for some reason.  I'm going to try to rewrite the code in ES5 to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140027/discussion-between-richa-garg-and-jhjanicki).

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Put the parameters in the URL. This is by far the best default.
   e.g. you might have the url `/map/beardy`, or `/map?name=beardy`.
   You then access these in Map with `props.params.whatever` or parse `props.location.search` (e.g. using `qs` from npm).
2. `Use browserHistory.push`'s `state` argument which adds a hidden piece
   of data to the history frame. This preserves the ability to refresh the page, or go back and forward in history while preserving the data. The downside is that I can't send a link to someone else and have it load with the selection.
3. Use redux or similar to store the data in memory. The data will be lost when the page refreshes. This is pretty bad.

Comment: If i make changes to Reptiles.js:  <NavLink to="map/{reptile.id}">  See Map Here </NavLink>     and  <NavLink to="map/{country}">  then what changes to router.js would I need to make? Currently that Map route is <Route path="map" name="map" component={Map} country="Taiwan" reptile="Beardy"/> but when I only edit Reptiles.js it still doesn't work. How do I sync them? This is trying the 1st options, I still haven't attempted 2 and 3

Comment: @jhjanicki `path="map/:foo"` and then it'll be `props.params.foo`

Answer (score 0):

To your **first question**: *"how to pass props to links directly in components?"*. You can't, you do have some workarounds like the ones mentioned in other answers like creating a url that has some data in it and then retrieve it from the url when you load the component. But you can't pass custom props through  or .

However, you can pass custom props like you're doing in *router.js*, except that instead of

This is from your *router.js*

```
<Route path="reptiles" name="reptiles" component={Reptiles}/>
```

You could pass the props like this:

```
<Route path="/reptiles" render={() => <Reptiles name="reptiles" />} />
```

To your **second question**: *"how would you generate dynamic urls?"*

Suppose you're rendering your component  in  like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Reptile subtype="foobar" />
        )
    }
}
```

Then in Reptile.js you could create dynamic urls like this:

```
class Reptile extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavLink to={`/reptile/${this.props.subtype}`} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```